# asynchtask suddenly stop working android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my android application I'm using webservice so I freqently use GET,POST and PUT. I have one of the method to update a user account. it work perfectly for 1 week until today, I tried to use it the data hasn't been updated. I debugged the code everything work fine. I don't know where is the problem.why it has been stopped working. this is the class that I'm calling like this `new registerIdreg().execute(regId);`

```
   private class registerIdreg extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double> {

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        postData(params[0]);
        return null;
    }



    public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


        HttpPut httppost = new HttpPut("http://myserver/api/users/active_push/id/"+id_user);

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regId",valueIWantToSend));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Empty catch blocks just burn my eyes. Can you please add `e.printStackTrace()` there.

Comment: 'stop working' is not a proper description of whatever problem you're having.

Comment: If there's no error, is the web service returning data if run outside of Android (if possible)?

Comment: yes when i use REST client of google chrome it work and there is no error. i have used it for more than one week and i passed to another code. today i came back to test